# Is there any easy and systematic way to analyse circuits containing opamp and multiple diodes?

Tags: operational-amplifier, diodes, negative-feedback

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6Yq5t.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For instance the circuit above.I need a more systematic procedure then hit and trial.
Diodes have a cutin voltage of .7V and show ideal piece-wise characteristic

Comment: Hope this helps in the future: always label **all** your components, especially critical ones like your two diodes. If I wanted to refer to one of them, I'd have to write something awkward "the left one" instead of "D1" or so.

Comment: Also, you should be very clear about what model you have for your non-linear components. OK, you assume your opamp to be ideal, but what about the diodes? An ideal diode in *my* head has an exponential current curve in reverse direction, in a simplified thinking an ideal diode might simply be perfectly blocking. And that makes a big difference in circuits with ideal opamps, because if even a tiny current flows, an ideal opamp with a near-infinite amplification could lead to unbounded output, even if a real opamp wouldn't. So: careful modelling,+considering all states that your diodes can have.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all the standard rules for Opamps still apply, so,

- no current flows into inputs
- differential amplification is very high

And other than that, a simple "diode current is an exponential function of voltage" does the job pretty well.

> systematic procedure then hit and trial.

Then simply make a graph for your input voltage(s) and try to figure out in what operational state the diodes are (blocking, reverse breakthrough, linear forward bias, saturation).

You can basically make a table with all possible state combinations for all your diodes. Depending on how you model your diodes, that might be quite a few! Then, check by which input voltages these states can be achieved (or whether they are possible at all).

That's the most systematic you can do without doing a full parameterized simulation:

The "really" systematic procedure is writing a SPICE simulator or something similar.

Since you're clearly a student of electronics, the reason why you're looking at these circuits is to learn the tricks and higher-level patterns from which such nonlinear circuits can be built. The whole point of this exercise is that you don't *need* to do a systematic analysis – which would be so computationally intense that humans use computers to do them.

Comment: But it can be tiresome for some circuits containing multiple diode when current can follow different path to analyse first current direction and then voltage across each diode for each path .It would be helpful if some sort of elimination of outcomes can be done in a more optimized fashion then random hit and trial maybe better prediction of which diode to start testing first and proceeding in a fashion just needed help with that thought process.

Comment: That's **exactly** what I described when I said you should make a table for all states. Sorry, your expectation that "systematic" is less tiresome than "applying prior experience" is simply not generally true.

Comment: Use 0.6v at 1mA, 0.54v at 0.1mA, 0.48 volts at 0.01mA, 0.42 volts at 1uA, 0.36 volts at 0.1uA, and then apply 10 millivolts to input of the entire circuit.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Indeed, experienced engineers very seldom do really systematic analysis, because generally they recognise patterns. For example I looked at that diagram and went 'Oh, precision rectifier', also 'That opamp is heavily loaded, hope it ain't a TL071'. We all build mental libraries of familiar things that we don't need to do deep analysis on for most common cases, the real trick being to recognise those cases where we actually DO need to do the maths on the otherwise basically familiar.